# Probability that one normal (uncorrelated) variable is greater than another if the latter is positive

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

Assume that $X\sim N(0,\sigma_x^2)$, $Y\sim N(0,\sigma_y^2)$ and $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated. Can we solve analytically for  $\mathbb P(X>Y |Y>0)$?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to do it without knowing either the joint p.d.f of $(X,Y)$ or the conditional distribution of $X$ knowing $Y$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**   $\mathbb P(X>Y |Y>0) = \frac{ \mathbb P(X>Y,Y>0)}{ \mathbb P(Y>0)} = 2 \mathbb P(X>Y,Y>0)$

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then you can solve this easily. If not, I think you are not given enough information to solve it.

Comment: This is not exactly precise. [Normally distributed and uncorrelated does not imply independent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normally_distributed_and_uncorrelated_does_not_imply_independent).

Comment: @Cm7F7Bb ah of course my bad. edited

Comment: Thanks, that was somewhat clear to me. Can I proceed and solve analytically in a simple way from there (without involving bivariate normal between the correlated X-Y and Y)? You can assume independence X and Y.

Comment: If X and Y are independent, then the joint distribution of X and Y can be easily computed from the marginal distributions of X and Y ([see this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_probability_distribution#Joint_distribution_for_independent_variables)) And you should be able to compute $\mathbb{P}(X>Y, Y>0)$ knowing the joint distribution.